# Align window buttons to the right in GNOME fallback mode?

Tags: gnome, 11.10, window-buttons

There have been many a question on how to do it with `gconf-editor` in < 11.10, but how can I align the window buttons (close, minimize and maximize) to the right in Ubuntu 11.10?

Please close if it's a duplicate. I searched around but couldn't find anything. I'm in the `gnome-session-fallback` WM.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**The old way does work still**, you just have to be more patient with it:

Run (or do whatever you do - you'll need to install gconf2 for this one)

```
gconftool-2 --set /apps/metacity/general/button_layout \
 --type string "menu:minimize,maximize,close"
```

Then log out. And log back in again.

Before 11.10 the change was instant but I'm guessing now the settings are loaded out of gconf into something else at login and don't refresh until you've started a new session.

Comment: Thank you ever so much! This brings me one small step closer to being able to put up with 11.10. It's in a VM at the moment.

Comment: Yeah I was a bit worried when I first upgraded. I struggled to get the menus in the right place (but fixed it), I still can't get Cardapio working yet (developer needs to improve it for GTK3) and there's been some weirdness with shortcuts thanks to Compiz/Unity but I'm slowly getting into a position where things are the same as they were in Natty. It's a shame people have to fight so hard just to keep things the way they want them but that's "progress", I guess.

Comment: "progress" indeed. I do like it, but not when it goes in the wrong direction! Thanks for protecting my question - I can see it being visited quite a lot.